# Cuda programming on Android Phone?

Tags: graphics-card, android, gpu, cuda

I'm looking for the most compact device that features a Cuda compatible device (optimal would be size of a smartphone / tablet).

In the end I would like to install the Caffe Neural Network library on the device, so it should be capable of running Cuda 6.5 (and have a least 150 MB of GPU memory).

Did anyone have the same problem yet?

I've found the [Nvidia Shield Tablet](https://shield.nvidia.de/store/tablet/k1). It features a Tegra K1 GPU, which should be Cuda capable. 
However I'm not sure since it seems to be some kind of integrated graphics chip. Also 8GB of memory as proclaimed [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tegra-k1-processor.html) sounds suspicious. Maybe they mean rather some sort of shared memory where they the share the RAM-memory with the GPU...

Comment: Hi mcExchange , questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly

Comment: I was checking all StackExchange forums available. This one seemed to be the most appropriate. It's a tech related question. Where else should I have asked this question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with [hardwarerecs](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) , you could take a look to their [help](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) to see if the question could fit there.

Comment: Oh ok, I must have overlooked that one. Thank you

Comment: Take a look, especially to the closed questions before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OP stated Tegra K1 indeed does have CUDA (CUDA 6.5) support as stated in CodeWorks for Android 1R4 release notes. However K1 isn't the only CUDA capable android device. According to release notes;

- TK1 Reference Device (Ardbeg)
- Google Project Tango Tablet
- MiPad
- SHIELD Tablet 8
- SHIELD Android TV

support CUDA as well. There seems to be versional differences between different devices so supported features may differ too. You should follow up-to-date documentation from GameWorks site for detailed info and examples.

1. [NVIDIA CodeWorks for Android](https://developer.nvidia.com/codeworks-android)
2. [CodeWorks for Android 1R4 Release Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/mobile/codeworks_android/codeworks_android_release_notes.htm)